# Cassandra can't running as a service with /etc/init.d/cassandra start

Tags: cassandra

I installed a new EC2(on AWS) with Ubuntu 13 and prepare all environment to run my server.

When I run Cassandra with:

```
  /bin/cassandra -f
```

everything go OK. I can connect successfully with cassandra-cli using the command

```
cassandra-cli -host localhost -port 8070
```

but when I close the Cassandra and run as a service

```
 /etc/init.d/cassandra start
```

the same cassandra-cli doesn't answer. I look around and try what they say, Cassandra is running normally, see what prompt:

```
root@ip-10-252-42-119:/bin# ps ax|grep cassandra
 5231 ?        Ss     0:00 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log -cp /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-server.properties -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1370739469.hprof -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1370739469.log -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms294M -Xmx294M -Xmn73M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
 5495 ?        Ss     0:00 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log -cp /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-server.properties -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1370739904.hprof -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1370739904.log -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms294M -Xmx294M -Xmn73M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
 6328 ?        Ss     0:00 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log -cp /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-server.properties -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1370741075.hprof -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1370741075.log -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms294M -Xmx294M -Xmn73M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
 6364 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cassandra
```

I looked at system.log, but I do not see anything wrong:

```
 INFO [main] 2013-06-09 01:26:00,389 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 126) JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_21
 INFO [main] 2013-06-09 01:26:00,395 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 127) Heap size: 300679168/300679168
 INFO [main] 2013-06-09 01:26:00,397 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 128) Classpath: /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.0.12.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar
```

What can I do to run Cassandra like a normal service?

Comment: to run cassandra as a service use `/bin/cassandra` just without the -f flag

Comment: Did you try `cassandra-cli -host \`hostname\` -port 8070` ? Also, try just using `cassandra-cli -host \`hostname\``. however there is no reason why it will not connect to the service, if connects in foreground mode.

Comment: Lyuben Todorov, thanks helps a lot

Comment: If anyone else is having these issues, try using debian as there seems to be a whole lot of Java issues straight out of the box with Ubuntu. I did manage to get this working on Ubuntu, though it was a painfull process (which I'm not even sure of anymore), but I now use debian for Cassandra which works straight of the box, no fuss.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `/bin/cassandra`

This will run cassandra as a background service/deamon

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SupervisorD" to run cassandra as a service:

http://supervisord.org/